# Removing the battery icon in xib file

Tags: storyboard, xib, nib

How does one remove this annoying battery icon located at the top right of a xib file?  I am using a xib for my UI layout of a particular tableView cell.  I am doing some tight frame setting in the top right area and this battery image simply makes this difficult.  Why should the battery be in my tableview cell that has no chance of occupying the statusbar frame anyway and how/can I remove this?

Answer (score 13):

In your xib file, show the right side section, and select 'Show the attributes inspector' tab, then under 'Simulated Metrics', set 'status Bar' to none.